# How to put a shopping cart total in a session

Tags: php

I am building a shopping cart using sessions. How do I put the total amount in a session such that it changes as the user adds or removes from the shopping cart. This is the function I use in getting my total price:

```
public function grand_total($grand_total, $coupon){
    if ($coupon != 0){
      $discount = $grand_total * 0.1;
      $actual = $grand_total - $discount;
      return $actual;
    }else{
      return $grand_total;
    }
  }
```

On cart.php, where all items being bought are shown, I use this to display the total:

```
grand_total($grand_total, $discount);
```

How do I put this total in session such that it can be accessible in any page and also changes as items are added or removed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access session using $_SESSION. So in your case, you can have

```
$_SESSION['grand_total'] = grand_total($grand_total, $discount)
```

whenever the grand total is updated.

And anywhere you want to display the grand total, just reference `$_SESSION['grand_total']`, like

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['grand_total'] ? $_SESSION['grand_total'] : 0; ?>
```

Comment: So it should be "return $actual = $_SESSION['grand_total']" in the function?

Comment: you may want to do `return $_SESSION['grand_total'] ? $_SESSION['grand_total'] : 0` in case the grand total is not set yet.

Comment: public function grand_total($grand_total, $coupon){
   if (){
      return $_SESSION[$actual] ? $_SESSION[$actual] : 0;
    }else{
        return $_SESSION[$grand_total] ? $_SESSION[$grand_total] : 0;
    }
  }

Comment: what is $actual?  does it resolve to a string that is being used as index of $_SESSION? Also, did you call start_session() first?  See http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php